# How can I import Jquery into React

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs

I have to do an animation, so I thought I would use what I know - Jquery;

I tried copying and pasting the uncompressed version from their website into a new file and importing it with: import "./jquery.js". I also added script at the end of the body with cdn as source. Heck, I even opened up console, typed npm install jquery, it installed and when I said import $ from 'jquery' it still gave me an error.

When I used copy-paste method, the "$ is undefined" went away, but I got a new error:
Failed to compile
./src/jquery.js
  Line 10559:38:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 10560:2:   'define' is not defined  no-undef

I have a small animation script written in another file which is linked to the index.js.

How do I fix this issue? I have tried all of the above mentioned methods, nothing worked.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/tree/v1-stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/#usage-jquery

```js
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    });
```

But if you ask my opinion, you should not use jquery and react at the same time :)

Comment: I need to animate something and only way I know is jQuery. I have been trying to use something with react, but can't wrap my head around :D

Comment: haha figured it out then you want to use what you are strong :) as I said you can try plugin.